# symfony2 authentication

Tags: database, security, symfony

I want to create SF2 authentication against a database, I used the officiel documentation of SF2, http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html, the problem is that the check does not work, I don't know way, I didn't get any error, after entering the user information I still in same page /login, without errors, I don't really get it.

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
  TEST\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    algorithm: sha512
    encode-as-base64: true
    iterations: 10


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: TESTUserBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    login:
        pattern: ^/(login|reset|accueil)
        anonymous: true
    main:
        pattern: /.*
        form_login:
            check_path: /check_login
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        security: true
        anonymous: false

access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    #- { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
    #- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

the problem is that the error always null, this is my login form

```
            {% if error == 1 %}
        <span class="pw-alert">E-mail et/ou mot de passe erroné(s)</span>
        {% endif %}
                <form action="{{ path('_security_check_user') }}" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="email" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" name="login"/>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The check_path should be `/login_check` and not `/check_login` (works for me).
For the provider try to indicate your class this way : `TEST\UserBundle\Entity\User` (since you want to log them from database you have to give the path of you user entity and not user controller). And add `provider: main` to you main firewall.

Does it help?

Comment: I changed the /check_login (Actually I think it works if you indicate it in the check_path ), I have changed the class for provider  from TESTUserBundle:User to  TEST\UserBundle\Entity\User but it not working, the problem persist, the last part add provider: main to your main firewell I didn't get it, can you explain a little bit :p

Comment: Usually you've to declare to your firewall whitch provider it must use and in your case it's the main provider (where you declare your entity class) also can you show us your user entity and your twig login form? Did you add the {{ error.message }} ? As you can see there : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form

Comment: yes a had added the error messages and it does work its always null,

Comment: I had edited my question for clarification, the Entity user is the same in the offcial doc

Comment: can you had this like in the doc : `{% if error %}<div>{{ error.message }}</div>{% endif %}` it'll display you the real error (if there is one) and for your logincontroller did you take the one of the official doc too? (cf my previous link) ?